# What's the difference between Visual Studio 2019 Preview and Visual Studio 2019 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

On 4 December 2018 there was Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1 released. On 27 February 2019 they released Preview 4 and at the same time Visual Studio 2019 RC.
I would assume that when releasing RC they discontinue the Preview branch but now they are released in pair (Preview 4.1 & RC.1, Preview 4.1.Svc1 & RC.1 Svc1). Release Notes of Preview now redirect to RC (i.e. "*Visual Studio 2019 Preview 4.1 is a servicing update to Preview 4 and contains the same functionality as the Visual Studio 2019 RC.1 release*").

What's the purpose of maintaining both versions? On Preview Release Notes I only found the following: *"Visual Studio 2019 Preview now contains the same functionality as the Visual Studio 2019 RC release. However, the Preview does not provide go-live rights"*. What are "go-live rights"? What are the different reasons for releasing Preview?

Links:

- [Release Notes for Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview)
- [Release Notes for RC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [RC and Preview 4 are the same, just different Release channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-release-candidate-rc-now-available/).

> With this release, we’re introducing two product “channels”: the
>   release channel and the preview channel. Starting today, Visual Studio
>   2019 RC is available in the release channel
>   (visualstudio.com/downloads) and Visual Studio 2019 Preview 4 is
>   available in the preview channel (visualstudio.com/preview). Both
>   versions can be installed and used side-by-side and, **right now, both
>   channels contain the same bits.**
>
> Starting April 2, the release channel (RC) build can be upgraded to
>   our generally available (GA) release, which will be ready for
>   production use. The preview channel will continue to offer an early
>   look at upcoming features, just as you’ve become accustomed to in
>   Visual Studio 2017.

After release of VS2019, preview channel gets preview 1 of 2019 Update 1 similar to VS2017:

[image]

So until the final 2019 is out, preview and RC are the same.